# Help on extracting a string pattern, typically conference id from a meeting invitation

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

Somebody can help me to extract matching pattern string?
I want to extract conference Id from a meeting invite.

A typical example would be

< meeting agenda text... 
....
Conference Id : *12322#
....
more text....
/>

Platform: .Net, Language: C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a regular expression...

```
var str = "< meeting agenda text... .... Conference Id : *12322# .... more text.... />";
var re = new Regex(@"Conference Id : \*(\d+)");
var m = re.Match(str);
if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
}
```